# What's the meaning of "visiting fellowship"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "visiting fellowship"?

For example:

> He also held visiting fellowships at Goldsmiths College in London

Comment: Please see also: [academia.se]

Answer (score 1):

A *visiting* scholar is an academic who is resident at one institution but temporarily working in an academic capacity with a different institution. In some cases, the function may be similar to that of an *adjunct*, but an adjunct has no permanent institutional affiliation.

For example, a professor at LexCorp University may take a sabbatical, and while on sabbatical, teach a course at the College of Smallville. The College of Smallville may grant her the title *Visiting Professor*. A scientist who is a fellow of, say, the Metropolis Academy of Science, who is invited to collaborate on a research project with fellows of the Gotham Association of Chemists, may be recognized as a *Visiting Scientist* of the Gotham Association.

Answer (score 0):

Visiting Fellowships enable scholars to undertake research and publication in collaboration with the staff where he/she is visiting, in most cases, an institution.
In your example, most likely he is also doing collaborating research with staff at Goldsmith College in London.